# Pixi.js - How to fix texture blur on mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, pixi.js

I have 2 separate projects which draw a randomized grass tilemap, which are using 2 different methods (personally want to see which is more convenient/efficient). One is using only Canvas, the other using Pixi.js. They both work fine on PC, but when I use `cordova` to compile it as an Android app, `pixi.js` tileset has a blur

**Regular Canvas/Cordova**
[image]

**Pixi.js/Cordova**
[image]

If you look closely, the 'grass' in `Regular Canvas` is sharp, but it's blurred in `Pixi.js`

I've tried playing around with the settings with no avail. `window.devicePixelRatio` reads `3` on mobile

**PIXI.jS**

```
PIXI.settings.autoDensity = true;
PIXI.settings.ANISOTROPIC_LEVEL = 0;
//PIXI.settings.SCALE_MODE = PIXI.SCALE_MODES.NEAREST;

let app = new PIXI.Application({
    width: screenSize.x,
    height: screenSize.y,
    antialias: true,
    autoResize: true,
    resize: (screenSize.x, screenSize.y),
    transparent: false,
    resolution: window.devicePixelRatio,
    rootRenderTarget: {
        resolution: window.devicePixelRatio
    },
    backgroundColor: 0x061639,
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some playing around, I found `PIXI.settings.RESOLUTION = window.devicePixelRatio;` must be declared. Everything became sharper now

[image]